# Performance impact of embedding videos in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Please like to know the effect/impact of embedding a video clip in an online banking application am working on. How would the video affect overall performance?

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks. But to what extent does it affect the application say if the video is hosted on Youtube and i just provide a frame on the application for viewing?

Comment: The effect/impact should be measured specifically. It's a huge guessing exercise otherwise. It could be huge. It could be small. No way to answer that, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. Anything will impact performance. Sending "hello" is worse then sending "hi" performance wise. It's up to you to determine if the additional information is worth sending.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you intend to display the video on the website. Few options are:-

- use Standalone video players like flowplayer , silverlight based players , flashplayers or
  even HTML video tags to display the video using embed tag.
- Use an Iframe to display the youtube video playback url.
- Embed You Tube Video in your Html Code.
- let the user upload a video to your website and using FFMPEG convert it to desired
  format. Remember browsers are choosy about which format they can play. MP4 is the most 
  favoured  one.

Peformance hit originates from the fact that the video player has to loadup the video from your video storage whether it is filesystem or database . If the video is being streamed from your webhost , it is definitely going to affect performance of your site . The best option to minimise performance degradation is to upload the video to youtube and then display it in your website . I have just begun a tutorial on my blog http://netizen4u.blogspot.in, where Iam using the option of displaying the video after uploading through my website using youtube API or even copy-pasting the Youtube playback url and embedding the video link into database. Here the Youtube Servers are bearing the load of video playback and it reduces your webhost bandwidth requirements.Performance hit is minimal.